# What are the differences between the multiplayer in Dungeon Siege 1 and 2?

Tags: dungeon-siege, dungeon-siege-2

Are there any major differences between the multiplayer for Dungeon Siege 1 and 2? I have played 1 a few years ago, and thought it was very Diablo-like and easy to pick up.  Is Dungeon Siege 2 the same way?

Does one have a longer multiplayer campaign than the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- In DS2 multiplayer you play the single-player campaign, the only difference being you are playing with other people.
- You aren't limited to only controlling 1 character per player - 2 players can have 3 characters each for example (not sure if those are the correct numbers though).
- You can save the state of the multiplayer campaign and resume it later.
- Every player gets his own quest rewards.

One thing didn't change, though: you can use a single-player-campaign raised character in multiplayer, but not the other way around.